# Registration with two steps, next fragment by button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, retrofit, registration

I want to handle user registration in my app. I red that using fragments is the best way to handle it.
I prefer using button to move to registration finish fragment, than swype.

I have to send few field to another and finally send all of data by Retrofit.

Any solution?

Comment: What have you done for it ,start making fragment

Comment: I have two layouts and fragments

Comment: Please specify where are you facing problem in code

Comment: I don't know how send data between fragments after click button in first

Comment: You will find links search for how to communicate with fragments,though you have to create interface in fragment and your hosting activity should implement that interface and call those interface method from  hostactivity to inform other fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a Callback to save the values on your activity.

First create the interface:

```
public interface ActivityCallback {

    void sendData(String data1,String data2);

}
```

Then make your activity implements this interface:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCallback{
    private ArrayList<String> arrayData = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    @Override
    void sendData(String data1, String data2){
        this.arrayData.add(data1);
        this.arrayData.add(data2);
    }
    ...

}
```

Then on your fragment, when you decide to go to the next step:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{
    private Button nextButton;
    private EditText text1;
    private EditText text2;
    protected ActivityCallback callback;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        callback = (ActivityCallback) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ...
        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                callback.sendData(text1.getText().toString(),text2.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if it helps you!, if it does, mark it as the Correct Answer, Thanks!

Comment: Okay but how get data in second fragment?

Comment: ...and run a second fragment?

Comment: The second fragment should do the same with the callback, once you completed the registration, you will have all the data in your arrayData activity to do whatever you need.

Comment: you can navigate to the second fragment from the "sendData()" method